# Using javascript with flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Hi guys I am having a problem with flash and javascript I wish to to invoke a click on the code below when the page unloads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function save() {
    var appWidth = 24;
    var appHeight = 24;
    var flashvars ={
        'event_handler': 'microphone_recorder_events', 
        'upload_image': 'images/upload.png'
    };
    var params = {'name' :'wmode',' value' : 'transparent'};
    var attributes = {'id': "recorderApp", 'name':  "recorderApp"};
    swfobject.embedSWF("recorder.swf", "flashcontent", appWidth,      appHeight, "10.1.0", "", flashvars, params, attributes);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't get your question. Please describe your problem a bit more in detail. What should be called when? Where should be clicked. What is unloading?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to trigger a flash event from javascript. Check the this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653710/trigger-flash-button-object-via-javascript) for a solution.