# Control Piecemaker 2 using javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

[Piecemaker 2](http://www.modularweb.net/#/en/piecemaker) is so cool!
Even though I'm not a flash fan, I have to hand it to them... its nice and cool and smooth!

One thing though... Is there any way to control it using javascript / jquery?
To be more specific, I would like to be able to:
- start / pause the transitions
- change its content (images etc) dynamically

Am I asking for too much?

Comment: Not without modifying the Flash code. You should take a look at the existing jQuery sliders though (http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/). You might find something comparable.

Answer (score 0):

eNot without modifying the Flash code.you will have to set permissions in flash to accept the communication, also with out the original source you would not know, or where to reference assets that the swf was scripted: For examples; variables, sprites , placeholders and functions that determine the interactivity within the SWF.

You will proberly find the transitions are codded with a library so it will not be possible to simply  pause the SWF as theres proberly only 1 frame aswell.

you will need to reference that scripted animation and wich may not consist of a pause method at all.

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. The flash code is open but I don't speak flash... Thank you all the same mate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do it is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653710/trigger-flash-button-object-via-javascript). Unfortunately my flash skills are non-existant. Anyone with flash skills out there to give it a go? Piecemaker 2 is a cool piece of code and I think many people could use the ability to control it using javascript.