# Programatically clicking Flash elements on a page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am trying to work on a plugin for Chrome that automates clicking on various buttons/links/etc using JQuery, and have had success in the past using JQuery to manipulate the DOM tree for similar projects.

For my latest plugin, I have run up against a wall. The elements that I am trying to click on seem to be Flash objects, because when I right click on the buttons to try to inspect them with FireBug, I get the Adobe Flash Player context menu. My question is, is it possible to use JQuery to programatically click on Flash elements, and if so, how would I go about approaching something like that?

Thanks

Comment: any solution yet? i need to automate a record feature and for that, i need to invoke flash click event.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947293/988587

Seems to be difficult without selenium : http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2257304